# How do I modify and deploy Edit.aspx in Kentico 7?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system, kentico

We are on kentico 7 and for some reason, none of my edits to Edit.aspx are showing up locally or on our dev server.  Usually, I just modify a .aspx or .cs file on my local machine and they appear on my local server when I launch the site.  Is there a special way to modify/deploy this file?  The file full path is: site\CMSModules\Content\CMSDesk\Edit\Edit.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to NOT modify any of the Kentico base files.  BUT I'm assuming here since you're on v7.x that you're most likely not upgrading to a new version any time soon so this will come down to how your site is set up.  Is it a website or a web project?  Website will have an /App_Code directory.

If you have an /App_Code directory, then you'll make the changes to your ascx and .cs files and copy them to your production server.  If you have a web project, then you'll need to build the project and redeploy the site, including the new dll, to your production server.

Don't ask how to copy the code to your servers because that will be something you need to figure out on your own on how to access your production servers.  Don't reply with any of your dev or prod server info, it's not a good idea at all.

Comment: And I would also try clearing .Net cache - in some cases the older version of the code was incorrectly cached - this was fixed in newer Kentico versions.

Comment: My actual problem was that I was expecting the changes to display on the page view and not the form view.  When I didn't see the changes on page view, I thought it was a deployment issue.  The changes were in fact correctly showing on the form view.  This is still the correct answer for my initial issue.  Thanks!